# TypeConvertor with GenecicType Error

Tags: c#, generics, typeconverter

Anyone know how i repair this error:

> Code generation for property '...' failed.   Error was: 'Unable to
>   cast object of type'   '{The
>   namespace}.EventType`1[System.Drawing.Color]'   '{The
>   namespace}.EventType`1[System.Object]'

```
public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
{
    if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
    {
        Type gT = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Type cT = typeof(EventType<>).MakeGenericType(gT);

        ConstructorInfo cI = cT.GetConstructor(new Type[]
        {
            gT, gT, gT, gT, gT
        });

         // The error if from this line.
         // If i make EventType<Color> its works fine.
         // Any idea how i make this to work ?
        EventType<object> eT = (EventType<object>) value;

        return new InstanceDescriptor(cI, new object[]
        {
            eT.None, eT.Over, eT.Down, eT.Outside, eT.Invalid
        });
    }
    else if (destinationType == typeof(string))
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException($"The destination type: {destinationType}");
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(EventTypeConverter))]
public class EventType<T>
{
    public EventType(T none, T over, T down, T outside, T invalid)
    {
        None     = none;
        Over     = over;
        Down     = down;
        Outside  = outside;
        Invalid  = invalid;
    }

    public T None { get; set; }
    public T Over { get; set; }
    public T Down { get; set; }
    public T Outside { get; set; }
    public T Invalid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is some heavy reflection stuff, which should *usually* not be necessary. May I ask what the underlying problem is? Maybe there is an easier solution...

Comment: Oh, and please provide a [mcve]. My compiler does not recognize `EventType`.

Comment: Is a custom class. Not so hard. But i added.

Comment: An `EventType<Color>` is not a subtype of `EventType<object>`. Thus, you cannot cast one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes do not support variance, hence `EventType<T>` cannot be cast to `EventType<object>`.

The easiest I see (and usually do in such cases) is to move as much as possible of the code related to generic type arguments in a generic method and call it via reflection or DLR dynamic dispatch.

For instance, the private method:

```
private static InstanceDescriptor ToInstanceDescriptor<T>(EventType<T> eT)
{
    var gT = typeof(T); 
    var cI = typeof(EventType<T>).GetConstructor(new Type[]
    {
        gT, gT, gT, gT, gT
    });
    return new InstanceDescriptor(cI, new object[]
    {
        eT.None, eT.Over, eT.Down, eT.Outside, eT.Invalid
    });
}
```

and calling it dynamically:

```
if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
{
    return ToInstanceDescriptor((dynamic)value);
}
```

Comment: Now i try to understant this. Thanks.